# PlatformException trying to readCharacteristic on flutter blue

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter

i am trying to read all the characteristics from all services from a device with the plugin https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue but it is throwing me this error:

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (24425): PlatformException(read_characteristic_error, unknown reason, may occur if readCharacteristic was called before last read finished., null)
E/flutter (24425): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:547:7)
E/flutter (24425): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter (24425): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24425): #2      BluetoothDevice.readCharacteristic (file:///C:/Users/Downloads/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.3.3/lib/src/bluetooth_device.dart:56:10)
E/flutter (24425): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24425): #3      _ListTabState._connectToDevice._readCarachteristics (file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/lib/tab_base.dart:125:49)
E/flutter (24425): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24425): #4      _ListTabState._connectToDevice._showServices (file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/lib/tab_base.dart:157:27)
E/flutter (24425): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24425): #5      _ListTabState._connectToDevice._connect.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/my_app/lib/tab_base.dart:197:24)
E/flutter (24425): #6      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316:10)
E/flutter (24425): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:330:11)
E/flutter (24425): #8      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:578:14)
E/flutter (24425): #9      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:694:11)
E/flutter (24425): #10     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:654:7)
E/flutter (24425): #11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (24425): #12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

Here is the code i am using:

```
_readCarachteristics(services) async {
  for (BluetoothService service in services){
    _characteristics = service.characteristics;
    for (BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic in _characteristics) {
      final List<int> value = await _device.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
  }

_services = await device.discoverServices();
_readCarachteristics(_services);
```

I read this issue: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/57 but could'nt manage to solve it. Thanks for your support.

**UPDATED**

It seems that there are specific characteristics sent by the beacon that are composed in a special way that is breaking the readCharacteristic method. They are supposed to contain two subtypes of uuid that are not been read by the readDescriptor function.

Answer (score 3):

There are three services out of which the third one should be used to read and write characteristic.The first two are generic and the third one is custom service using which it will work. Try this :

```
_scanResult.device.discoverServices().then((services){
        services[2].characteristics[0].read();
    });
```